# Why do Electrical cables use the NY* naming convention?

Tags: cables

I did some research on cables and found that most cable types are named like so: NYY/NYA/NYM. The weird part of this naming system is that its meaning does not match up with the abbreviations. For example:
N = Copper core
Y = PVC insulation
Y = PVC insulation
Are the letters some kind of product code? If so, is there a documentation where I can find out more about this? Sorry if i'm unclear, i'm not an electrical guy.

Comment: Which came first? Naming system or the cables?

Comment: See if https://diary-of-electric.blogspot.com/2018/12/meaning-of-cable-types-or-nomenclature.html#:~:text=NYM%20cable%20is%20a%20cable,more%20than%20one%20cable%20core helps.

Comment: any particular cables? Audio cables or house wiring for example? Any particular region?

Comment: Well, it's about the cables' naming system as a whole, so no particular examples